How to put a rectangle shape under a Board Assembly View in Altium Draftsman Document
I have a basic Board Assembly View in Altium Drafstman Document:

I want to color part of the board assembly view purple to indicate where something needs to be placed, but whenever I try to place the rectangle shape it covers the board assembly view and it won't show the components.

If I try placing the rectangle first then placing the board assembly view then only the text will appear and components will still be covered.

I don't see any settings that allows you to put a component behind another. How can I go about doing this? Perhaps there is a better way to do this? All I want to do is show the components and have there be a purple background color for part of the PCB

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).
